# INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_5'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, regression

When training a regression model, I got this message:

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1197] [/device:CPU:0] 
(DEBUG INFO) Executor start aborting (this does not indicate an error and you can ignore this message): 
INVALID_ARGUMENT: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder/_5' with dtype float and shape [32,268][[{{node Placeholder/_5}}]]
```

below is the model:

```py
def build_strats(D, max_len, V, d, N, he, dropout, forecast=False):
    demo = Input(shape=(D,))
    demo_enc = Dense(2*d, activation='tanh')(demo)
    demo_enc = Dense(d, activation='tanh')(demo_enc)
    varis = Input(shape=(max_len,))
    values = Input(shape=(max_len,))
    times = Input(shape=(max_len,))
    varis_emb = Embedding(V+1, d)(varis)
    cve_units = int(np.sqrt(d))
    values_emb = CVE(cve_units, d)(values)
    times_emb = CVE(cve_units, d)(times)
    comb_emb = Add()([varis_emb, values_emb, times_emb]) # b, L, d
#     demo_enc = Lambda(lambda x:K.expand_dims(x, axis=-2))(demo_enc) # b, 1, d
#     comb_emb = Concatenate(axis=-2)([demo_enc, comb_emb]) # b, L+1, d
    mask = Lambda(lambda x:K.clip(x,0,1))(varis) # b, L
#     mask = Lambda(lambda x:K.concatenate((K.ones_like(x)[:,0:1], x), axis=-1))(mask) # b, L+1
    cont_emb = Transformer(N, he, dk=None, dv=None, dff=None, dropout=dropout)(comb_emb, mask=mask)
    attn_weights = Attention(2*d)(cont_emb, mask=mask)
    fused_emb = Lambda(lambda x:K.sum(x[0]*x[1], axis=-2))([cont_emb, attn_weights])
    # embed text input
    texts = Input(shape=(33792,))
    text_enc = Dense(2*d, activation='tanh')(texts)
    text_enc = Dense(d, activation='tanh')(text_enc)
    conc = Concatenate(axis=-1)([fused_emb, text_enc, demo_enc])
    fore_op = Dense(V)(conc)
    op = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(fore_op)
    model = Model([demo, times, values, varis, texts], op)
    if forecast:
        fore_model = Model([demo, times, values, varis, texts], fore_op)
        return [model, fore_model]
    return model
```

and

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_2 (InputLayer)           [(None, 880)]        0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_3 (InputLayer)           [(None, 880)]        0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_4 (InputLayer)           [(None, 880)]        0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 embedding (Embedding)          (None, 880, 50)      6750        ['input_2[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 cve (CVE)                      (None, 880, 50)      364         ['input_3[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 cve_1 (CVE)                    (None, 880, 50)      364         ['input_4[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 add (Add)                      (None, 880, 50)      0           ['embedding[0][0]',              
                                                                  'cve[0][0]',                    
                                                                  'cve_1[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 lambda (Lambda)                (None, 880)          0           ['input_2[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 transformer (Transformer)      (None, 880, 50)      39508       ['add[0][0]',                    
                                                                  'lambda[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 input_5 (InputLayer)           [(None, 33792)]      0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 2)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 attention (Attention)          (None, 880, 1)       5200        ['transformer[0][0]',            
                                                                  'lambda[0][0]']                 
                                                                                                  
 dense_2 (Dense)                (None, 100)          3379300     ['input_5[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 100)          300         ['input_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 lambda_1 (Lambda)              (None, 50)           0           ['transformer[0][0]',            
                                                                  'attention[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 dense_3 (Dense)                (None, 50)           5050        ['dense_2[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)                (None, 50)           5050        ['dense[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)      (None, 150)          0           ['lambda_1[0][0]',               
                                                                  'dense_3[0][0]',                
                                                                  'dense_1[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 dense_4 (Dense)                (None, 134)          20234       ['concatenate[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 3,462,120
Trainable params: 3,462,120
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

and training loop

```py
for e in range(1000):
    e_indices = np.random.choice(range(N_fore), size=samples_per_epoch, replace=False)
    e_loss = 0
    pbar = tqdm(range(0, len(e_indices), batch_size))
    for start in pbar:
        ind = e_indices[start:start+batch_size]
        e_loss += fore_model.train_on_batch([ip[ind] for ip in fore_train_ip], fore_train_op[ind])
        pbar.set_description('%f'%(e_loss/(start+1)))
    val_loss = fore_model.evaluate(fore_valid_ip, fore_valid_op, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
    val_losses.append(val_loss)
    print ('Epoch', e, 'loss', e_loss*batch_size/samples_per_epoch, 'val loss', val_loss)
    train_loss = e_loss*batch_size/samples_per_epoch
    train_losses.append(train_loss)
    with open("Exp0/train_losses.txt", "a") as train_f:
        train_f.write(str(train_loss)+"\n")
    with open("Exp0/valid_losses.txt", "a") as valid_f:
        valid_f.write(str(val_loss)+"\n")        
#     # model should be saved here after each epoch in case of unexpected disconnection
#     files.download(model_path)
    
    if val_loss < best_val_loss:
        best_val_loss = val_loss
        fore_model.save_weights(fore_savepath)
        best_epoch = e
    if (e-best_epoch)>patience:
        break
```

Does one ignore the message as stated () or the error suggests some rather serious issue that requires actions? If the error requires tending, what to do to tackle it?